# JQUERY Retrieve and Remove Previous Sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a form I want to be able to add and remove textboxes and labels. Each textbox has a label preceding it, as such the label is the sibling. I am trying just select the sibling of the textbox so I remove it as well when textbox is removed. **My question is how can I select the previous label**. Removing the textbox is simple, its the last textbox with a name I pass as a parameter into the function(since I re-use it) .  Removing textbox works fine, its just the preceding label that's a challenge. Here is my function.

```
function remove(someName) {

 var count = $('input[name=' + someName + ']').length;

 if (count > 1) {
     $('input[name=' + someName + ']:last').remove();
     $(this).closest('label.numbers').remove();
     /*
     I have tried this one below but it doesn't work
     $('label.numbers > input[name=' + someName + ']:last').parent().remove();

     This too doesn't work.
     $('label.numbers > input[name=' + someName + ']:last').offsetParent().remove();

     */
 }
```

**UPDATE**
Here is a snippet of my Razor code for a clear picture

```
            <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupportingDocumentation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div>
                    <label class="numbers"> 1 </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SupportingDocumentation, new { @class = "SupportingDocumentation" })

                    <input type="button" value="+" class="roundButton" onclick="add('SupportingDocumentation', 'SupportingDocumentation')" />
                    <input type="button" value="-" class="roundButton" onclick="removeElement('SupportingDocumentation')" />
                </div>

                <div> 
                    <label class="numbers"> 2 </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SupportingDocumentation, new { @class = "SupportingDocumentation" }) 
                </div>
                <div> 
                    <label class="numbers"> 3 </label>
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SupportingDocumentation, new { @class = "SupportingDocumentation" }) 
                </div>

                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupportingDocumentation, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: A fiddle would also be nice :), go here http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Sam am using asp.net mvc, I have updated the question to include just a snippet of the relevant Razor code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, textbox is already removed when you try to use its reference to select the label, rather -

a) You can remove them one by one like this -

```
var txtbox = $('input[name=' + someName + ']:last');
var lbl = txtbox.parent().find('label.numbers');

txtbox.remove();
lbl.remove();
```

b) Or simply remove the parent div, it will remove everything inside it -

```
var div = $('input[name=' + someName + ']:last').parent();
div.remove();
```

c) Or make html inside the div as empty -

```
var div = $('input[name=' + someName + ']:last').parent();
div.html('');
```

**Edit**:

An example fiddle for your case by using solution (a) -

http://jsfiddle.net/15morm22/3/

Comment: It only removes the textbox(which was working before). I have updated the code to show how I use it on Razor in asp.net mvc 5.

Comment: Ok, I see. In your description you mentioned label is the parent, but its rather a sibling. Modified my answer.

Comment: The label comes first having the number of the textbox, isn't it then the parent as this their relationship can be written like this `"label.numbers > 'input[name=' + someName + ']:last'"`

Comment: No, it is a sibling. Parent is the div which contains both label and input in your example. So, that relationship is not applicable.

Comment: I am yet to get it working.Is there a way in jQuery that I can select previous element, i.e the element before what the selector returned?

Comment: Yes, there is - element.prev(). But my answer should also work. Take a look at the fiddle I added.

Comment: Yeah I just checked and it worked, however I cant remove the div in my case as all the textboxes and labels are within the same div tag. Doing that would in an instance remove all the textboxes and labels instead of just one, the last one.

Comment: Ok, then use solution (a) of my answer. I updated the link to fiddle.

Comment: I have just used element.prev() as you had suggested and it worked. I am also posting that as answer. I edited and tried the code on the jsfiddle you had put up earlier, thanks.

While I arranged all TBs in one single div, your answer is still a valid answer to my question. Am also editing the question since I realised I wanted to remove the sibling and not the parent.

Answer (score 0):

As Sam had pointed out, I was rather trying to remove a sibling and not the parent. Here is the jquery code that worked for me, all thanks to Sam's efforts.

```
$("#removeBtn").on("click", function(){

    var textbox = $('input[name=' + 'ThisElement' + ']:last').parent();
    var label = textbox.prev();

    textbox.remove();
    label.remove();

    return false;
});
```

And  [here](http://jsfiddle.net/15morm22/4/)  is the link to the jsfiddle snippet